# best way to compare sequence of letters inside file?

Tags: python

I have a file, that have lots of sequences of letters.
Some of these sequences might be equal, so I would like to compare them, all to all.
I'm doing something like this but this isn't exactly want I wanted:

```
for line in fl:
line = line.split()
for elem in line:
    if '>' in elem:
        pass
    else:
        for el in line:
            if elem == el:
                print elem, el
```

example of the file:

```
>1
GTCGTCGAAGCATGCCGGGCCCGCTTCGTGTTCGCTGATA  
>2
GTCGTCGAAAGAGGTCT-GACCGCTTCGCGCCCGCTGGTA    
>3
GTCGTCGAAAGAGGCTT-GCCCGCCACGCGCCCGCTGATA  
>4
GTCGTCGAAAGAGGCTT-GCCCGCTACGCGCCCCCTGATA  
>5
GTCGTCGAAAGAGGTCT-GACCGCTTCGCGCCCGCTGGTA  
>6
GTCGTCGAAAGAGTCTGACCGCTTCTCGCCCGCTGATACG  
>7
GTCGTCGAAAGAGGTCT-GACCGCTTCTCGCCCGCTGATA
```

So what I want if to known if any sequence is totally equal to 1, or to 2, and so on.

Comment: (1) How many sequences do you have per line? (2) Are you trying to find if a sequence in a line matches other sequences in the same line OR if a sequence in a line matches any other sequence in the same file? (3) Can you post some sample lines?

Comment: How many sequences do you want to compare?

Comment: DO you just need to know there are matches, or do you need the location too?

Comment: How large is the file -- specifically, can it be stored in memory?

Comment: Right now, I'm would only compare around 700sequences, so yes it would be nice to have the location also :)

Comment: @FM not very large, around 1532 lines and 73Kb. It's a text file

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the goal is to simply group like sequences together, then simply sorting the data will do the trick.  Here is a solution that uses [BioPython](http://biopython.org/wiki/Biopython) to parse the input FASTA file, sorts the collection of sequences, uses the standard Python [itertools.groupby](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) function to merge ids for equal sequences, and outputs a new FASTA file:

```
from itertools import groupby
from Bio       import SeqIO

records = list(SeqIO.parse(file('spoo.fa'),'fasta'))

def seq_getter(s): return str(s.seq)
records.sort(key=seq_getter)

for seq,equal in groupby(records, seq_getter):
  ids = ','.join(s.id for s in equal)
  print '>%s' % ids
  print seq
```

Output:

```
>3
GTCGTCGAAAGAGGCTT-GCCCGCCACGCGCCCGCTGATA
>4
GTCGTCGAAAGAGGCTT-GCCCGCTACGCGCCCCCTGATA
>2,5
GTCGTCGAAAGAGGTCT-GACCGCTTCGCGCCCGCTGGTA
>7
GTCGTCGAAAGAGGTCT-GACCGCTTCTCGCCCGCTGATA
>6
GTCGTCGAAAGAGTCTGACCGCTTCTCGCCCGCTGATACG
>1
GTCGTCGAAGCATGCCGGGCCCGCTTCGTGTTCGCTGATA
```

Comment: Thanks! It's a really nice trick, that I don't even had thought about it

Answer (score 2):

The following script will return a count of sequences. It returns a dictionary with the individual, distinct sequences as keys and the numbers (the first part of each line) where these sequences occur.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
from collections import defaultdict

def count_sequences(filename):
    result = defaultdict(list)
    with open(filename) as f:
        for index, line in enumerate(f):        
            sequence = line.replace('\n', '')
            line_number = index + 1
            result[sequence].append(line_number)
    return result

if __name__ == '__main__':
    filename = sys.argv[1]
    for sequence, occurrences in count_sequences(filename).iteritems():
        print "%s: %s, found in %s" % (sequence, len(occurrences), occurrences)
```

Sample output:

```
etc@etc:~$ python ./fasta.py /path/to/my/file
GTCGTCGAAAGAGGCTT-GCCCGCTACGCGCCCCCTGATA: 1, found in ['4']
GTCGTCGAAAGAGGCTT-GCCCGCCACGCGCCCGCTGATA: 1, found in ['3']
GTCGTCGAAAGAGGTCT-GACCGCTTCGCGCCCGCTGGTA: 2, found in ['2', '5']
GTCGTCGAAAGAGGTCT-GACCGCTTCTCGCCCGCTGATA: 1, found in ['7']
GTCGTCGAAGCATGCCGGGCCCGCTTCGTGTTCGCTGATA: 1, found in ['1']
GTCGTCGAAAGAGTCTGACCGCTTCTCGCCCGCTGATACG: 1, found in ['6']
```

**Update**

Changed code to use `dafaultdict` and `for` loop. Thanks [@KennyTM](https://stackoverflow.com/users/224671/kennytm).

**Update 2**

Changed code to use `append` rather than `+`. Thanks [@Dave Webb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3171/dave-webb).

Comment: You should use `result[sequence].append(line_number)` rather than `result[sequence] = result[sequence] + [line_number]` as the concatenation needlessly creates a new list.

Answer (score 2):

In general for this type of work you may want to investigate [Biopython](http://biopython.org/) which has lots of functionality for parsing and otherwise dealing with sequences.

However, your particular problem can be solved using a dict, an example of which Manoj has given you.

Answer (score 2):

Comparing long sequences of letters is going to be pretty inefficient.  It will be quicker to compare the hash of the sequences.  Python offers two built in data types that use hash: `set` and `dict`.  It's best to use `dict` here as we can store the line numbers of all the matches.

I've assumed the file has identifiers and labels on alternate lines, so if we split the file text on new lines we can take one line as the id and the next as the sequence to match.

We then use a `dict` with the sequence as a key.  The corresponding value is a list of ids which have this sequence.  By using [`defaultdict` from `collections`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) we can easily handle the case of a sequence not being in the `dict`; if the key hasn't be used before `defaultdict` will automatically create a value for us, in this case an empty `list`.

So when we've finished working through the file the values of the `dict` will effectively be a `list` of `list`s, each entry containing the ids which share a sequence.  We can then use a list comprehension to pull out the interesting values, i.e. entries where more than one id is used by a sequence.

```
from collections import defaultdict
lines = filetext.split("\n")
sequences = defaultdict(list)

while (lines):
    id = lines.pop(0)
    data = lines.pop(0)
    sequences[data].append(id)

results = [match for match in sequences.values() if len(match) > 1]
print results
```

Comment: Great idea, but the implementation is very inefficient due to removing elements with pop(0) -- an O(n) operation per element for Python lists, so the total time complexity will be O(n^2).  Not a worry for small examples, but not ideal for large collections of sequences.  Best not to use this recipe verbatim.