# error comparing sequences - string interpreted as number

Tags: python, biopython

I'm trying to do something similar with my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3675895/best-way-to-compare-sequence-of-letters-inside-file).
My purpose is to join all sequences that are equal. But this time instead of letters, I have numbers.

alignment file can be found [here - phylip file](http://pastie.org/2486250)

the problem is when I try to do this:

```
records = list(SeqIO.parse(file(filename),'phylip'))
```

I get this error:

```
ValueError: Sequence 1 length 49, expected length 1001000000100000100000001000000000000000
```

I don't understand why because this is the second file I'm creating and the first one worked perfectly..

Below is the code used to build the alignment file:

```
fl.write('\t')
fl.write(str(161))
fl.write('\t')
fl.write(str(size))
fl.write('\n')

for i in info_plex:
    if 'ref' in i[0]:
        i[0] = 'H37Rv'
    fl.write(str(i[0]))
    num = 10 - len(i[0])
    fl.write(' ' * num)
    for x in i[1:]:
        fl.write(str(x))
    fl.write('\n')
```

So it shouldn't interpret 1001000000100000100000001000000000000000 as a number since its a string..

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: Could you show the (start of the) PYHLIP file in your question? In particular line one.

Comment: I've provided a link to the alignment file. I will edit my question and write in front phylip file.

Comment: Interesting... two things strike me as odd in your file. First, your identifiers are numeric (don't start with a letter), and secondly your sequences are also numeric (not DNA or protein).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your PHYLIP file is broken. The header says 161 sequences but there are 166. Fixing that the current version of Biopython seems to load your file fine. Maybe use len(info_plex) when creating the header line.

P.S. It would have been a good idea to include the version of Biopython in your question.

Comment: basic error.. I though I had verify this, apparently not..Thank you.. Regarding your previous comment. Normally samples have a numeric code, and not always you have DNA or proteins data. Depends what your doing.. binary data is also used, for instance presence/absence, etc

Comment: @peterjc Personally, I didn't succeed employing _Biopython_ to analyze the file "phylip" given in link by ``pavid``. Also, the code in my answer analyzes without problem the broken file. - I upvote your answer for signaling the need to give the version; there are too much questions with unsufficient info in them

Answer (score 1):

The code of Kevin Jacobs in your former question employs [Biopython](http://biopython.org/wiki/Biopython) that uses sequences of type `Seq` that

> « are essentially strings of letters like AGTACACTGGT, which seems very
>   natural since this is the most common way that sequences are seen in
>   biological file formats. »
>
> « There are two important differences between `Seq` objects and standard
>   Python strings. (...)
>
> First of all, they have different methods. (...)
>
> Secondly, the **Seq object has an important
>   attribute**, `alphabet`, which is an object describing what the individual
>   characters making up the sequence string “mean”, and how they should
>   be interpreted. For example, is AGTACACTGGT a DNA sequence, or just a
>   protein sequence that happens to be rich in Alanines, Glycines,
>   Cysteines and Threonines?
>
> The alphabet object is perhaps the important thing that makes the `Seq`
>   object more than just a string. **The currently available alphabets for
>   Biopython are defined in the Bio.Alphabet module.** »
>
> http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/tutorial/Tutorial.html

The reason of your problem is simply that `SeqIO.parse()` can't create `Seq` objects from a file containing characters for which there is no  `alphabet` attribute able to manage them.

.

So, you must use another method. Not try to plate an inadapted method on a different problem.

Here's my way:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter
import re

regx = re.compile('^(\d+)[ \t]+([01]+)',re.MULTILINE)

with open('pastie-2486250.rb') as f:
    records = regx.findall(f.read())

records.sort(key=itemgetter(1))

print 'len(records) == %s\n' % len(records)

n = 0
for seq,equal in groupby(records, itemgetter(1)):
    ids = tuple(x[0] for x in equal)
    if len(ids)>1:
        print '>%s :\n%s' % (','.join(ids), seq)
    else:
        n+=1

print '\nNumber of unique occurences : %s' % n
```

result

```
len(records) == 165

>154995,168481 :
0000000000001000000010000100000001000000000000000
>123031,74772 :
0000000000001111000101100011100000100010000000000
>176816,178586,80016 :
0100000000000010010010000010110011100000000000000
>129575,45329 :
0100000000101101100000101110001000000100000000000

Number of unique occurences : 156
```

.

### Edit

I've understood MY problem: I let 'fasta' instead of 'phylip' in my code.

'phylip' is a valid value for the attribute `alphabet`, with it it works fine

```
records = list(SeqIO.parse(file('pastie-2486250.rb'),'phylip'))

def seq_getter(s):  return str(s.seq)

records.sort(key=seq_getter)

ecr = []

for seq,equal in groupby(records, seq_getter):
    ids = tuple(s.id for s in equal)
    if len(ids)>1:
        ecr.append(  '>%s\n%s' % (','.join(ids),seq) )                   

print '\n'.join(ecr)
```

produces

```
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,

>154995,168481
0000000000001000000010000100000001000000000000000
>123031,74772
0000000000001111000101100011100000100010000000000
>176816,178586,80016
0100000000000010010010000010110011100000000000000
>129575,45329
0100000000101101100000101110001000000100000000000
```

There is an incredible amount of characters `,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,` before the interesting data, I wonder what it is.

.

But my code isn't useless. See:

```
from time import clock
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter
import re
from Bio       import SeqIO


def seq_getter(s):  return str(s.seq)
t0 = clock()
with open('pastie-2486250.rb') as f:
    records = list(SeqIO.parse(f,'phylip'))
records.sort(key=seq_getter)
print clock()-t0,'seconds'



t0 = clock()
regx = re.compile('^(\d+)[ \t]+([01]+)',re.MULTILINE)
with open('pastie-2486250.rb') as f:
    records = regx.findall(f.read())
records.sort(key=itemgetter(1))
print clock()-t0,'seconds'
```

result

```
12.4826178327 seconds
0.228640588399 seconds
```

ratio = 55 !

Comment: Thank you for your response. Although it's not DNA, the method works with binary data.. If it's only intended for DNA data, it should give some kind of error

Comment: @pavid I don't know Biopython. How do you indicate to the module ``Bio`` that it must treat a file's content as binary data ? Could you give the code, please ?

Comment: I don't indicate.. Don't get me wrong, you're absolutely right and I've not even though about that.. That why now I was asking why did it work.. but perhaps it was a bug and it is fix now..

Comment: Thank you! Your code is faster :) and another way to achieve the same